# ListView with loadmore button replacing the old data

Tags: android

I am developing android app in that i want to display json data in listview with load more button, but when i click load more button old data is replaceing by new one i want both and old and new data to be displayed.Lihstview should show all data whats wrong in the code below

```
public class Newjava extends Activity {
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
CustomAdapter1 adapter2;
CustomAdapter1 adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<FeedAddress> arraylist;
String url = "http://xxxx.vdv.com/api/fvn/page1";
String arraymovie = "all";
public String string;
ListView listView;
int i = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    arraylist = new ArrayList<FeedAddress>();
    // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in
    // JSONfunctions.class

    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);

    try {
        // Locate the array name
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonobject.getJSONObject("appname");
        jsonarray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("kfnh");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = (JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            FeedAddress map = new FeedAddress();
            jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Retrive JSON Objects
            map.setMovieName(post.getString("movieName"));
            map.setName(post.getString("movieActors"));
            map.setMovieId(post.getString("movieId"));
            String imageUrl = "http://www.xxhbc.com/upload/dv/thumbnail/"
                    + post.getString("moviePhoto")
                    + post.getString("moviePhotoExt");
            map.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
            System.out.println("ldhslhdljh " + imageUrl);
            // Set the JSON Objects into the array
            arraylist.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
    btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

    // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
    listView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

    // Getting adapter
    adapter = new CustomAdapter1(this, arraylist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Listening to Load More button click event
     * */
    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Starting a new async task
            i += 1;
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    //   Create a progressdialog
         mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Newjava.this);
         // Set progressdialog title
         mProgressDialog.setTitle("APP Name");
         mProgressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         // Set progressdialog message
         mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
         mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         // Show progressdialog
         mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<FeedAddress>();
        // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in
        // JSONfunctions.class

        String URL = "http://zvzvs.vczx.com/api/v/page"
                + i;
        System.out.println("new url " + URL);
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);

        try {
            // Locate the array name
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonobject
                    .getJSONObject("fvvzx");
            jsonarray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("allmovies");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = (JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                FeedAddress map = new FeedAddress();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.setMovieName(post.getString("movieName"));
                // map.setName(post.getString("movieActors"));
                map.setMovieId(post.getString("movieId"));
                String imageUrl = "http://www.vsv.com/upload/vc/thumbnail/"
                        + post.getString("moviePhoto")
                        + post.getString("moviePhotoExt");
                map.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
                System.out.println("ldhslhdljh " + imageUrl);
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
        adapter = new CustomAdapter1(Newjava.this, arraylist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setting new scroll position
        listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
        updateList(string);
    }
}

public void updateList(final String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter1(Newjava.this, arraylist));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"position[]" ,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            FeedAddress newsData = (FeedAddress) o;
            System.out.println("hgsh " + string);
            System.out.println("next " + newsData.getMovieId());

            Intent intent = new Intent(Newjava.this,
                    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("feed", newsData.getMovieId());
            intent.putExtra("actor", newsData.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your code...

Comment: If you are using ArrayList to store data then you should check that you are not clearing the list before adding data into it.For more help,you need to post your code.

Comment: Please show us **[what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)**

Comment: i think you clear the old array values.if you get clear answer means share the code what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It replaces data because you recreate adapter every time. You should create adapter once and then add to it more data, not recreate it.